# Can Anyone Tell Me What This Weird Screen Means - New Mac Mini on First Startup

Tags: mac, boot, mac-mini

Hey I am setting up my stepfathers computer and I go to turn it on for the first time and this screen pops up. I've never seen it before, can anyone tell me what it means?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mouse needs to be on. Look underneath your mouse and you'll see that.

Comment: ah, i'm not using an apple mouse. so I guess this one just isn't compatible?

Comment: I'm sure you can. There's no way to skip that screen/setup? Might just be a friendly reminder that the mac-mini can't detect the stock mouse?

Comment: It's looking specifically for a Bluetooth wireless mouse because your one isn't detected. Try with a USB mouse for initial setup and then switch to your own wireless mouse afterwards.

Comment: i just want to say, how am i supposed to be able to tell that that image is of the bottom of a mouse?

Comment: It's white and shaped like a mouse with an optical/laser thingy ;) Only reason I know this is because my work uses this as their public computers and I had a hard time using the mouse.

Comment: I only recognized it because of the battery door tab that matches the older model I own.  If not for that I would have never guessed it's a picture of a mouse.

Comment: You'd think a "Make sure your mouse is connected" message would save a lot of confusion.